# Add global try/catch to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there some way to wrap the entire page in a try/catch, so that I can catch any error from any script that is executing?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onerror) instead of a big `try/catch`.

You could actually do some useful things in the error handler, like posting the error information to your server so you know when things are breaking on your page.

Comment: I use this exact method to catch javascript errors and then submit an AJAX report that I store in the database. Helps me debug things that are rare to catch

Comment: @Mikhail: I updated to say just that exactly when you posted your comment :)

Answer (score -5):

Turn on the debugger and break on error.

You don't want to catch every error in the entire page on production code. That's horrible.

Comment: Agreed - it's hacky, but I'm trying to add jQuery stuff to an existing page, and want my code to run even if the existing scripts have errors.

Comment: Actually you do want to do this on production code to log front end exceptions to the server.