# How to catch any JS error in a page without using try-catch-finally many times?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a 1000+ long Javascript file with many functions and many functions calls.

Since I'm modifying the code all the time and any error breaks page loading (I'm loading pages dinamically), I would like to print on screen (no console.log) any Javascript error that occurs.

I know I can do it by using

```
    try { <code> } catch(err) { ... }
```

for every piece of code, but since it's only for debug purposes, I want my code to remain clean.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `window.onerror`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror

Comment: Take a look to this other question to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901605/add-global-try-catch-to-javascript