# TypeError: r is not a function in Production Build

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am currently trying to use this [VueCarousel package](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/) for my web app, but I am getting this error in my production app:

```
TypeError: r is not a function
    at t (vue.common.prod.js:11:68600)
    at s.__patch__ (vue.common.prod.js:11:70431)
    at t._update (vue.common.prod.js:11:43128)
    at s.o (vue.common.prod.js:11:77577)
    at In.get (vue.common.prod.js:11:26615)
    at In.run (vue.common.prod.js:11:27259)
    at Ge (vue.common.prod.js:11:17853)
    at Array.<anonymous> (vue.common.prod.js:11:21774)
    at fn (vue.common.prod.js:11:21202)
```

I am certain that there is an issue with how I have imported the package, but so far I have not been able to find the cause.

This is how I am importing the carousel in my main `app.js` file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Carousel, Slide } from "vue-carousel";
import CustomCarousel from "./components/employees/CustomCarousel.vue";

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        Carousel,
        Slide,
        CustomCarousel,
    },
});
```

I am also using the carousel package in a custom carousel Vue component, and it is being imported into the component like so:

```
<script>
import { Carousel, Slide } from "vue-carousel";

export default {
    name: "CustomCarousel",
    components: {
        Carousel,
        Slide,
    },
};
</script>
```

In my code, I was also getting this warning:
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-carousel'.`

I was assuming that this was causing my carousel to not show up, so I created a *.d.ts file that declared this module.

I have also removed the importing of the carousel from the specific Vue components to see if that would solve my issue, but that did not seem to work either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what's wrong with this lib. .d.ts is a different problem that is not related. Unless you can find a similar problem in repo issues or make it reproducible for other users, currently only you can debug it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375813/how-to-effectively-debug-minified-js-files , then navigate to the first entry in the stack.